# BouncyCastle OCSP response in .net

Tags: .net, x509certificate, bouncycastle, ocsp

I'm making an OCSP request using BouncyCastle with a certificate I know its valid. My problem is that I'm getting an UNKNOWN certificate status. I know this means something went wrong in the server and it can return the state of the certificate.

Is there a way, within the BouncyCastle framework, to get an error description, an exception or some sort of message that could help me figure out exactly why is the server unabled to handle the verification of this certificate?

Comment: There are two `status` in the ASN1 `OCSPResponse` structure, the `OCSPResponseStatus` which indicate the OCSP Service status for the request itself not for certificate (possible values `successful,malformedRequest,internalError,tryLater,sigRequired,unauthorized`) for this `status` you can get additional information. The second `status` is the `CertStatus` which could be (`good`,`revoked`,`unknown`). As you comment "status UNKNOWN" I answer assuming you're asking about the second one, but I'm suspicious that maybe you were asking about `OCSPResponseStatus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [RFC6960 OCSP Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960) defines that OCSP response has to add the follow information for each certificate included in the OCSP Request:

> ...
> The response for each of the certificates in a request
> consists of:
>
> o  an identifier of the certificate for which revocation status
> information is being provided (i.e., the target certificate);
>
> o  the revocation status of the certificate (good, revoked, or
> unknown); if revoked, it indicates the time at which the
> certificate was revoked and, optionally, the reason why it was
> revoked;
>
> o  the validity interval of the response; and
>
> o  optional extensions.    ...

As is defined in the RFC only when certificate status is `revoked` additional information is added to the OCSP Response(time and optionally revocation reason), when status is each `good` or `unknown` no other information is added.

You can see that in the ASN.1 definition for `CertStatus` in this document which is:

```
 CertStatus ::= CHOICE {
       good        [0]     IMPLICIT NULL,
       revoked     [1]     IMPLICIT RevokedInfo,
       unknown     [2]     IMPLICIT UnknownInfo }

   RevokedInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
       revocationTime              GeneralizedTime,
       revocationReason    [0]     EXPLICIT CRLReason OPTIONAL }

   UnknownInfo ::= NULL
```

So even BouncyCastle has a way to parse this OCSP Response information, you can't get additional detail information for `unknown` certificates. If you check the class `org.bouncycastle.asn1.ocsp.CertStatus` which represents this structure you can see the same:

```
public CertStatus(ASN1TaggedObject    choice)
{
    this.tagNo = choice.getTagNo();

    switch (choice.getTagNo())
    {
    case 0:
        value = new DERNull();
        break;
    case 1:
        value = RevokedInfo.getInstance(choice, false);
        break;
    case 2:
        value = new DERNull();
    }
}
```

Like specification says `good(0)` and `unknown(2)` has `NULL` as info, and only for `revoked(1)` more information is added.

Anyway if you're curious about BouncyCastle at least in java (I suppose that also in C# version) there are the classes to work with OCSP protocol, take a look at classes in the `org.bouncycastle.asn1.ocsp` package which represents `OCSPRequest` and `OCSPResponse` elements in ASN.1 format as defined in the RFC6960.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @albciff. I can see now i can't expect more info with the unknown status. I have already look into the OCSPRequest and OCSPResponse and there is no more information there

Thanks for the help